# Does Mike Ehrmantraut ever kill an unarmed man?

Tags: breaking-bad

Mike, in *Breaking Bad*, has a decent body count. But I can't recall him ever shooting anybody that wasn't a threat to him. Jessie, Walt, and Gus have all killed defenseless people.

Has Mike ever killed an unarmed man?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mike kills Leonel Salamanca ([S03E08, I See You](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/I_See_You)) via lethal injection (on orders from Gus Fring) while he's recovering in the ICU following the shootout with Hank Schrader. There was a small threat that Leonel could inform to the DEA on Gus and Walt, and the much bigger threat (near certainty) that he would tell the other cartel bosses that Gus was the one who green-lit the hit on Hank, but he was unarmed and was definitely not an imminent threat to Mike at the time of the killing.

Comment: Nice catch. I missed that implication.

Comment: "As Gus departs, the police race upstairs where medical staffers are attempting CPR on Leonel, who has suddenly flat-lined. Their resuscitation attempts fail and Leonel dies. Amid the commotion, Mike slips away unnoticed, discarding a syringe as he leaves. It is clear that Gus's fried chicken delivery was a distraction to allow Mike to administer Leonel a lethal injection."

Comment: I doubt that he was ever a threat to inform to the DEA - it seems like most of the cartel members have an unwritten rule to never help the authorities, even when it would destroy their enemies.

Comment: @MattHealy After watching those few episodes again, I think you're right. The bigger threat was that Leonel would tell the other cartel boss that Gus was the one that okayed the hit on Hank.